# Jawbone API results not as expected

Tags: api, jawbone

I am querying Jawbone API for up with following HTTP request :

```
https://jawbone.com/nudge/api/v.1.0/users/@me/moves?start_time=1368392836&end_time=1399928836
```

I started using UP24 in March, 2014 and with above request, I get data for March and April (till April 18, 2014) but not after that. The data is continuously synced with the app by my UP24 device which I can also see on the app. I am not sure why I am not getting data after April 18, 2014.

```
The epoch start time stamp corresponds to Sun, 12 May 2013 21:07:16 GMT
The epoch end time stamp corresponds to Mon, 12 May 2014 21:07:16 GMT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results are paginated and the next link is supplied at end of each response to get the next data